# How to get a standalone executable using opencv and eclipse (windows)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, opencv, static-libraries

I have written a small program to prepare an image which is later processed by a FPGA-Board. I need to have it run on any windows machine, even if opencv is not installed. I have read a lot of tutorials and answers on stack overflow, but none of that seems to work for me. I compiled opencv myself using Cmake and MinGW to build the static libraries (.a files). How do I get those in my project, which ones do I need and how do I link them? It seems like everytime I try to link the libraries I used before (when using dlls) seems to have some kind of dependency to other ones.

Thanks in advance,
Brillow

The error message is:

```
g++ "-LE:\\opencv\\staticlibs\\lib" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mwindows -o img_prep.exe main.o -lIlmImf -ljasper -lpng -ltiff -ljpeg -lz -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249 -lopencv_core249 
E:\opencv\staticlibs\lib/libopencv_highgui249.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.obj):grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text.unlikely._ZN2cvL16my_jpeg_load_dhtEP22jpeg_decompress_structPhPP9JHUFF_TBLS5_.constprop.52+0xce): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
E:\opencv\staticlibs\lib/libopencv_highgui249.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.obj):grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xe2): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:\opencv\staticlibs\lib/libopencv_highgui249.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0xe2 in section `.text$_ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have linked the following libraries in the MinGW linker:
[image: Libraries]

Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: img_prep InputImage" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat img, img_gray;
    Size size(800,600);

    img = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (!img.data) {
        cout << "Could not read the image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    resize(img_gray, img, size);

    cout << "Image successfully converted!" << endl;

    ofstream output;
    output.open("output.img", ios::binary);

    output.write((char *) img.data, img.rows * img.cols);
    output.close();

    imwrite("output.bmp", img);

    cout << "Image saved!" << endl;

    //Ergebnis anzeigen:
    namedWindow("Display", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display", img);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search for and read about *static linking*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that, but even when I statically link the libraries that I think I need for this project, there are still some unresolved dependencies that I can't seem to resolve, even if I change the order. That's why I'm asking for a basic guide, I think it has something to do with eclipse and MinGW

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your unresolved dependencies? Do you get linker errors? Can you please edit your question to include them in that case?

Comment: I recall that I got linker errors saying something like "undefined reference to 'jpeg...'". The linker error changed depending on the order I added the libraries in the MinGW linker. I will add the exact error message as soon as I get to my development machine.

Comment: I think OpenCV has something like build-in libs that it uses, so I do not think you should search too much for build it statically. Anyway, I have tried this on Linux, but when I have moved it to another Linux (Ubuntu->Centos) it did not worked... I do not know if this is the same for Winsows (98, 2000, NT, 7, Vista, 8)

Comment: I added the exact error messages and some details on how i set it up